# Making jQuery.load() work with SEO-friendly URLs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I have a very simple bit of code on a website

```
jQuery("#slist").load("sg-custom-code/SG-ajaxGetPastProds.php",{pd: jQuery(this).val()});
```

The path 'sg-custom-code' is off the root of the site. However the (Joomla) site uses SEO-friendly urls so it appends the apparent url of the page root (derived from the menu path) and tries to go to https://xxx.co.uk/everything-else/players/past-productions/sg-custom-code/.... and of course fails. The actual url should obviously be https://xxx.co.uk/sg-custom-code....

I can fix it by writing

```
jQuery("#slist").load("https://xxx.co.uk/sg-custom-code/SG-ajaxGetPastProds.php",{pd: jQuery(this).val()});
```

... but if a user then uses [www.xxx.co.uk](http://www.xxx.co.uk) instead of xxx.co.uk it will fail with a CORS error!

Any ideas for how to work around this?

Comment: Why not `/sg-custom-code/...`? Same result?

Comment: You are right - works fine. Many thanks.